# PHP/MySQL insert fails but no error message, syntax looks correct

Tags: php, mysql

This insert is not working, but I don't get an error message:

```
insert into Company (companyname, address, city, stateorprovince, postalcode, region, country, website, notes, previous) values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '', '')
```

I can't see anything wrong with it. No error, but the record does not appear in the table. Is there a way to show what the error is? Here is a screenshot of the table structure.[image: tablestructure]

Comment: It might be case-sensitive - in any case, you should see an error if you run it in phpMyAdmin, and if you're running it via a library in PHP, you can enable error-reporting and use functions to get the error thrown back by MySQL.

Comment: Please add your code where you executed the SQL query and checked for errors to your question.

Comment: You should wrap column names in backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try what @Qirel suggested, but here is the proper statement for Linux based machines. Windows is NOT case sensitive.

```
insert into Company (CompanyName, Address, City, StateOrProvince, PostalCode, Region, Country, WebSite, notes, previous) values ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '', '')
```

Comment: I don't think column names are case-sensitive (I'm on Linux and don't have a problem with that elsewhere), although I know the table name is. However, when I tried what you gave me in phpMyAdmin, I do now see there is a constraint on CompanyName that won't allow duplicates. I wish MySQL would return an error instead of just letting my code run through.

Comment: Are you echoing out any potential MySQL errors on the execution of your query?  And yes, judging by your database design, 'CompanyName' is set to Unique ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how to echo out potential errors. I do now see that the Unique is shaded differently, it is such a subtle color change I didn't see it. But now I can't figure out how to turn off the "unique" requirement, is that easy enough to do?

Comment: Sorry, I found where to remove the index. That seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for your help!